# Conda: Command not found; Miniconda

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

Install the Miniconda2 on my iMac.

```
    [d25gv047dhjr:~] keguoh% bash Desktop/Miniconda2-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh

    ...

    Prepending PATH=/Users/keguoh/miniconda2/bin to PATH in
    newly created /Users/keguoh/.bash_profile
```

But it won't work.

```
    [d25gv047dhjr:~] keguoh% conda
    conda: Command not found.
    [d25gv047dhjr:~] keguoh% cat .bash_profile 

    # added by Miniconda2 4.0.5 installer
    export PATH="/Users/keguoh/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"$$
```

I spent 3 more than 2 hours searching online for solutions, but none of them helped. Thanks!

BTW, the `.bash_profile` file looks like this:

```
    [d25gv047dhjr:~] keguoh% cat .bash_profile 

    # added by Miniconda2 4.0.5 installer
    export PATH="/Users/keguoh/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"
    [d25gv047dhjr:~] keguoh%
```

Comment: Have you restarted your terminal?

Comment: @ericmjl Yes, I retarted the terminal, even the computer. It returned the same result.

Comment: In your terminal, can you type `which python` to identify the path of your Python? Also, see whether `which conda` returns a path as well?

Comment: @ericmjl What I got for `which python` is `/usr/bin/python` and `which conda` gives `conda: Command not found.`

Comment: @ericmjl In fact, when I type `export`, it gives `export: Command not found.`. Do you think this may cause the problem?

Comment: @ericmjl I figured it out. I was not in the bash shell!